# bash echo replacing character with escape charackter

Tags: bash, ps

I am trying create top command by myself. I stucked at point where i read list of running processes

```
IFS=$'\n'

p=$(ps -A -o %cpu  -o vsz -o time -o %c  --sort -%cpu | head -3  )

for i in $p
do
    echo $i
done;
```

But when I try echo lines for some reason all "n" is replaced by "\n"

```
%CPU    VSZ     TIME COMMAND
16.3 9761940 04:06:02 firefox
9.2 3255916 02:19:27 Web Co
te
t
^C
```

I would appreciate any help

Thank you

Comment: The script runs fine on [rextester.com](http://rextester.com/l/bash_online_compiler), and no 'n' are substituted with newlines.

Comment: I guess the problem is leading ```$``` after ```=``` in ```IFS=$'\n'```. It is the same as saying set ```IFS``` to the value of variable ```$\n```, which leads to an empty value in most cases.

Comment: The problem is the separator used in ```IFS```. I've tested here setting ```IFS='^M'``` (That is ```CTRL+v``` followed by ```CTRL+M``` in vim) and it worked as you expected it to be.

Comment: This seems to work as well: ```IFS=$(printf "\n")```.

Comment: @accdias The syntax is correct, if the OP is actually using `bash`. In shells that don't support that kind of quoting, it's not a parameter expansion at all, so the `$` is treated literally. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you for help, when I quoted "$i" in echo, everything start working as should

Comment: @chepner, thanks for the explanation. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't running your script with `bash`, so your `IFS` is being set to three separate characters, rather than a single newline. One of those characters is `n`, so the unquoted expansion of `p` treats the letter `n` as a field separator.

Here's a simple example in `dash`:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ printf '%s' "$IFS" | hexdump -C
00000000  24 5c 6e                                          |$\n|
00000003
```

The same example in `bash`:

```
$ IFS=$'\n'
$ printf '%s' "$IFS" | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
```